# Как реализовать авторизацию из 2 таблиц в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В проекте 2 типа пользователей admin и user, admin`ы хранятся в стандартной таблице users.
Пользователи хранятся в таблице webusers.

Для разделения авторизация создал guard

```
    'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
            'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'admin_users',
            ],
        ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\WebUsers::class,
        ],
        'admin_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

    ],
```

теперь работает авторизация для users правильно. Но когда пытаюсь зайти в админку через стандартную форму авторизации выдается ошибка `These credentials do not match our records.` т.к. пользователь ищется через модель WebUsers и его там нет.

Что я пропустил? Как правильно разделить логику авторизации?

Comment: Посмотрите примеры с Интернета, к примеру [тут](https://techvblogs.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel-9)

Comment: вероятно ошибка в именах моделей:
WebUsers
User